# Nofollow on links in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, nofollow

Does anyone know where in CKEditor I can setup, so all links added will have rel="nofollow", even if the users don't specify it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a data filter as explained in this page that checks every link:
http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Data_Processor

This (untested) code should be more or less what you need:

```
editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(
{
    elements :
    {
        a : function( element )
        {
            if ( !element.attributes.rel )
                element.attributes.rel = 'nofollow';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this was excately what I was looking for.

Comment: You should add this code to body of instanceReady event. `CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function( ev ) { .... });`

Comment: How can I add rel="nofollow" only *external links*? @AlfonsoML

Comment: I see that you have already created a separate question and it has the correct answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416655/how-can-i-add-rel-nofollow-to-a-link-in-ckeditor-if-its-an-external-link

Answer (score 0):

Need wrapper:

```
editor.on('instanceReady',function(){...})
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code on page where ckeditor is loading

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(ev) {
      var editor = ev.editor;
      editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(
      {
          elements :
          {
              a : function( element )
              {
                  if ( !element.attributes.rel )
                      element.attributes.rel = 'nofollow';
              }
          }
      });
    })
```

Comment: How can I add rel="nofollow" only *external links*?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PHP Codeigniter with CKEditor and if you want to add rel="nofollow" only for external links you can modify the output of CKEditor before save it to database. Here the PHP function I use to modify:

```
function addNofollow($content) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom -> loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
    $x = new DOMXPath($dom);

    // Add rel="nofollow"
    foreach ($x -> query("//a") as $node) {
        $href = $node -> getAttribute("href");
        if (!strpos($href, site_base())) {
            $node -> setAttribute("rel","nofollow");
        } else {
            $node -> removeAttribute("rel");
        }
    }

    // Remove <script> tag
    $script = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');
    $remove = [];
    foreach ($script as $item) {
      $remove[] = $item;
    }
    foreach ($remove as $item) {
      $item -> parentNode -> removeChild($item); 
    }

    $newHtml = $dom -> saveHtml($dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0));
    return $newHtml;
}
```