# How can I add rel = "nofollow" to a link in CKEditor if it's an external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, nofollow

i want to give `rel="nofollow"` to my external links which its content managed by ckeditor.

**example.com = my site**

**externallink.com = any external link**

For example:

```
<p>
    Lorem <a href="https://example.com/an-article.html">ipsum</a> dolar
    <a href="http://externallink.com/example.html" rel="nofollow">sit</a> amet.
</p>
```

This solution:

```
editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules(
{
    elements :
    {
        a : function( element )
        {
            if ( !element.attributes.rel )
                element.attributes.rel = 'nofollow';
        }
    }
});
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6930940/1848929 adds `nofollow` to all `a` elements.

How can i filter only external links?

Also deep doc about CKEditor Data Processor: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Data_Processor

---

Note: Stackoverflow's text editor using these question's answer. Check two links' rel attribute in this question.

---

I'm using `<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.10/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>` from cdn on my pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it like;

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
        var editor = ev.editor;
        editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
                elements : {
                    a : function( element ) {
                        if ( !element.attributes.rel ){
                           //gets content's a href values
                            var url = element.attributes.href;
                           //extract host names from URLs 
                            var hostname = (new URL(url)).hostname;
                            if ( hostname !== window.location.host && hostname !=="youranothersite.com") {
                                element.attributes.rel = 'nofollow';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    })
```

Comment: Useful for ckeditor_4.20.0_full

Answer (score 4):

This solution also works in Internet Explorer:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
    var editor = ev.editor;
    editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
        elements : {
            a : function( element ) {
                if ( !element.attributes.rel ){
                    //gets content's a href values
                    var url = element.attributes.href;

                    //extract host names from URLs (IE safe)
                    var parser = document.createElement('a');
                    parser.href = url;

                    var hostname = parser.hostname;
                    if ( hostname !== window.location.host) {
                        element.attributes.rel = 'nofollow';
                        element.attributes.target = '_blank';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to compare hosts, something like this should work.

```
a : function( element )
    {
        if ( element.host !== window.location.host ) {
            element.attributes.rel = 'nofollow';
        }
    }
```

Comment: But my admin panel located in a subdomain. like https://panel.example.com, Is your solution involve https://example.com ?

Comment: than just hardcode the host you want instead of location.host

Comment: element.host returns undefined on console log

Comment: so what is element when you log it?

Answer (score 0):

Be shure to check hostname for empty value and for relative paths for do not add target='_blank' and  rel='nofollow' for links like "tel:+70000000000" or "mailto:email@address.ru"

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
    var editor = ev.editor;
    editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
        elements: {
            a: function (element) {
                var url = element.attributes.href;
                var parser = document.createElement('a');
                parser.href = url;
                var hostname = parser.hostname;
                if (hostname && hostname !== "localhost" && hostname !== window.location.host) { // если внешняя ссылка
                    if (!element.attributes.target)
                        element.attributes.target = '_blank';
                    if (!element.attributes.rel)
                        element.attributes.rel = 'nofollow';
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```